# someObject.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f,0f,0f) Not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, euler-angles

Here is my code when I try to rotate it

[image]

```
    IEnumerator cubeToBlock () {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(m_cube.GetComponent <Animation> ().clip.length-0.6f);
        block.Play();
        //! Adding RigitBody component to m_cube
        m_cube.AddComponent <Rigidbody> ();
        m_cube.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f,0f,0f);
        print(m_cube.transform.eulerAngles.x);
    }
```

It prints 0, so unity thinks that it is 0 but it isn't

[image]

What should I do I don't understand, I am new to Unity so if I missed some details please let me know

P.S. m_cube is surely the Main Cube component
And my parent is rotated in 90 deg

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your Cubes parent object is rotated slightly. Rotation and EulerAngles handles global rotation. If you want local rotation, try `transform.localEulerAngles` and make sure the parent transform is not rotated. If this isn't the problem, please reply.

Edit: The Inspector shows local position / rotation. That's why you need to use localEulerAngles or make sure the parent isn't turned or moved at all.

Comment: Yes the parent is rotated but I need it to be rotated what can I do in that case? :/

Comment: @NairiAregHatspanyan If you need the parent to be rotated, then use transform.eulerAngles. The inspector will say that it isn't rotated correctly because it is showing you the local rotation, and I don't know if you can change that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you to setup components in Editor when you can rather than adding them through scripting. Here I am referring to to the following line:

`m_cube.AddComponent <Rigidbody> ()`

Returning to your problem, if the cube should not be driven by forces you can set isKinematic true. You can use [RigidBody.MoveRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) for manipulating rotation. This will also update colliders.